# Is it fine to use useCallback inside another function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have (TypeScript) code like the following:

```
export const DemoComponent = React.memo((props: DemoComponentProps) => {
    const [state1, setState1] = React.useState<string | undefined>('');
    const [state2, setState2] = React.useState<string | undefined>('');
    const createF = (b: boolean) => React.useCallback(() => {
        /* code that does not depend on b or state2 */

        doSomething({ param: 'param', param2: b ? undefined : state2 });

        if (!b) setState2(/* some other value */);
    }, b ? [state1] : [state1, state2]);
    const f1 = createF(false);
    const f2 = createF(true);

    return (
        /* a few components, some of which use f1, while others use f2 */
    );
});
```

Will `useCallback` work as expected here (as if I just wrote it twice for `f1` and `f2` and rewrote all places that use `b`) or will it go wrong?

Comment: Why do you use React.memo  at the Component level ? (Remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil! and I don't think you need it here...). Also, `useCallback` is itself memoized, and React component will not re-render if its props don't change.

Comment: @Vinzzz it's basically our company's policy to use memo everywhere. I'm new here (in my company) so I can't really challenge this approach even if I wanted

Comment: Don't do stuff blindly... This kind of defensive programming ("use X everywhere, because... who knows ? better safe than sorry) is a bad practice

Comment: @Vinzzz I know it's memoized, I'm asking whether its memoization will still work correctly even though I'm not just using useCallback but wrapping it inside another function

Comment: @Vinzzz I know that I shouldn't optimize prematurely, but this memo was there long before me, so perhaps it is needed. I just used it here to show how this component is created

Comment: Although its not directly related to the question, I agree with @Vinzzz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `useCallback` like so due to [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

> **Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions**.
>
> - Call Hooks from React function components.
> - Call Hooks from custom Hooks

Hooks must be called on top-level of the function component.

Moreover, you should get eslint warning for it: `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

> React Hook "useCallback" is called in function ... which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

Comment: Actually, you can... it's the component which is memoized... which doesn't break the rule of hooks: the array of hooks defined into the component (state1, state2, callback) will always be the same

Comment: @Vinzzz Did you try? Check it, there is also eslint warning for it

Comment: @DennisVash thanks for that page, that is exactly what I was looking for. Althgough I guess I could use useCallback as I showed because order is still always the same

Comment: I don't know what "ND T" means ... IMO, the problem is not with the top-level `React.memo` wrapping the component - this seems perfectly fine. The problem is indeed with `createF` definition which wraps the hook `useCallback` with different dependencies depending on `b` . I think here, `useCallback` should be replaced by a `useMemo` , with constant dependency on `state1` and `state2`. (so you're right: this example BREAKS the rule of hooks)

Comment: @Vinzzz sorry this was my cat :P. Either way, This code is just not right in many ways, I think I explained why.

Comment: Do you know of a way to replace `createF` here? I mean, it's a lot of code that I marked with `/* code that does not depend on b or state2 */`, I would very much like to reuse it. It's also more complicated because `doSomething` actually sits in an `if` block that belongs in the `/* code that does not depend on b or state2 */`

Comment: I don't know, you need to add some context. Please just ask another question with minimal example, you can share a question link with me.